# Is it possible to take an arbitrary pointer as input argument in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to create a class that manages the Bit Band feature of an Cortex-M3 Device. For those who don't know: The processor maps every bit within a specific area to a whole word. This allows atomic set operations for specific bits. The class itself works with std::uintptr_t. For the constructor I'd like to allow an arbitrary pointer as I don't care what it's pointing to. It may be some struct defined in the device header.

My current implementation gives the constructors with:

```
Bitband(uintptr_t address, uint32_t bitNumber);
Bitband(void * ptr, uint32_t bitNumber);
```

my application calls the constructor like this:

```
Bitband foo(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&gpioPort->IDR), pin);
```

If I leave out he reinterpret_cast I get no known conversion for 'uintptr_t' and 'void *'.
Is there a clean way to get rid of that reinterpret_cast for every call and take an arbitrary pointer as an argument for my constructor?

*Edit:* Here is my current code for the class Bitband and my use for turing a led on or off:

**bitband.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>

class Bitband
{
public:
  Bitband(uintptr_t address, uint32_t bitNumber);
  Bitband(void * address, uint32_t bitNumber);

  inline void Set(bool val) const
  {
    uint32_t * const pData = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(this->bbAddress);
    *pData = val;
  }

  inline bool Get() const 
  {
    uint32_t * const pData = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(this->bbAddress);
    return *pData;
  }
private:
  static uintptr_t GetBitBandAddress(uintptr_t address, uint32_t bit);
  static bool IsSramAddress(uintptr_t address);
  static bool IsPeripheralAddress(uintptr_t address);

  uintptr_t const bbAddress;

/* Constants for bit band calculation for SRAM */
  static uintptr_t const sramStartAddress = 0x20000000;
  static uintptr_t const sramEndAddress   = 0x200FFFFF;
  static uintptr_t const sramBbBaseAddress = 0x22000000;

/* Constants for bit band calculation for Peripherals */
  static uintptr_t const peripheralsStartAddress = 0x40000000;
  static uintptr_t const peripheralsEndAddress   = 0x400FFFFF;
  static uintptr_t const peripheralsBbBaseAddress = 0x42000000;
};
```

**bitband.cpp**

```
#include "bitband.hpp"
#include <cassert>

Bitband::Bitband(uintptr_t address, uint32_t bitNumber) :
  bbAddress(GetBitBandAddress(address, bitNumber)) {}

Bitband::Bitband(void * address, uint32_t bitNumber) :
  bbAddress(GetBitBandAddress(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(address), bitNumber)) {}

uintptr_t Bitband::GetBitBandAddress(uintptr_t const address,
                                      uint32_t const bitNumber)
{
  uintptr_t bbBase;
  uintptr_t regionStartAddress;

  assert(Bitband::IsPeripheralAddress(address)
          || Bitband::IsSramAddress(address));

  /* Set the parameters depending on wether we are in peripherals region or sram
    region. */
  if(Bitband::IsSramAddress(address))
  {
    bbBase = Bitband::sramBbBaseAddress;
    regionStartAddress = Bitband::sramStartAddress;
  }
  else if(Bitband::IsPeripheralAddress(address))
  {
    bbBase = Bitband::peripheralsBbBaseAddress;
    regionStartAddress = Bitband::peripheralsStartAddress;
  }
  else
  {
    /* Invalid parameter */
    __breakpoint(0);
  }

  uintptr_t byteOffset = address - regionStartAddress;
  auto bitWordOffset = (byteOffset * 32) + (bitNumber * sizeof(uint32_t));
  auto bitWordAddr = bbBase + bitWordOffset;

  return bitWordAddr;
}

bool Bitband::IsSramAddress(uintptr_t address)
{
  return (address >= Bitband::sramStartAddress)
            && (address <= Bitband::sramEndAddress);
}

bool Bitband::IsPeripheralAddress(uintptr_t address)
{
  return (address >= Bitband::peripheralsStartAddress)
            && (address <= Bitband::peripheralsEndAddress);
}
```

It's used by my class led (for tests I Just turn on / off some leds)

**led.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32l1xx.h"                  // Keil::Device:Startup
#include "bitband.hpp"

class Led
{
public:
  Led(GPIO_TypeDef * const ledPort, uint16_t ledPin);
  inline void Set(bool newState) { this->ledOutputBitBand.Set(!newState); }
private:
  Bitband ledOutputBitBand;
};
```

**led.cpp**

```
#include <led.hpp>
#include <cassert>

Led::Led(GPIO_TypeDef * const port, uint16_t const pin) :
    ledOutputBitBand(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&port->ODR), pin)
{
  assert(pin < 16);

  /* Set port mode to push pull */
  port->MODER |= 1 << ( 2 * pin);
}
```

**Use within main application**

```
Led greenLed(GPIOD, 0);
greenLed.Set(true);
```

If I left out the reinterpret_cast I get the following messages:

```
Src/led.cpp(5): error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Bitband'
    ledOutputBitBand(&port->ODR, pin)
    ^                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

./Inc/bitband.hpp(9): note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'volatile uint16_t *' (aka 'volatile unsigned short *') to 'uintptr_t' (aka 'unsigned int') for 1st argument; remove &
  Bitband(uintptr_t address, uint32_t bitNumber);
  ^

./Inc/bitband.hpp(10): note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'volatile uint16_t *' (aka 'volatile unsigned short *') to 'void *' for 1st argument
  Bitband(void * address, uint32_t bitNumber);
  ^

./Inc/bitband.hpp(6): note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class Bitband
      ^

./Inc/bitband.hpp(6): note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
```

So I suppose that if I want to use the class Bitband in another context I'd have to use the reinterpret_cast again?

Comment: There should be no problem converting `&gpioPort->IDR` to `void*` (unless `IDR` is `const`). Please copy and paste the entire error message, and the code that causes it.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but what happens if you make the constructor a template that takes a pointer to the template type and then do the reinterpret cast inside the constructor itself? If you actually actually call the constructor with different pointer types this might end up enlarging your code (if it doesn't get optimized out) but it might make your calls cleaner looking. Alternatively you might consider using a macro to shorten the wordiness of your reinterpret cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the requirements that you have provided, that *is* the clean way to do it.

I don't really understand which constructor you intend to call (you do not make your goals clear) but, either way, a `reinterpret_cast` seems the closest to what is sensible.

It's verbose in order to remind you that you should revisit your design, and come up with one that does not require this conversion in the first place. Because we no longer live in the 1970s. :)

If you insist upon old styles, though, you could instead use a C-style cast:

```
Bitband foo((void*)&gpioPort->IDR, pin);
```

I implore you not to.